# Change the CSS of the Place Holder Text in the Filter Header

Tags: css, tabulator

I am trying to change the CSS of the "Filter" in tabulator. I want to change the size of the text and the colour, yet nothing is happening.

This is how I am displaying the columns:

```
{ title: 'Folder', field: 'title', width: '80%', formatter: '', align: 'left', headerFilter: 'input', headerFilterPlaceholder: 'Search Title', headerSort: false, sorter: '' },
{ title: 'Files', field: 'files', width: '20%', formatter: '', align: '', headerFilter: '', headerFilterPlaceholder: '1', headerSort: false, sorter: '' }
```

I have already tried the following CSS:

```
.tabulator-header-filter{
    font-size:10px;
    color: #F01;
}
.tabulator-placeholder{
    font-size:10px;
    color: #F01;
}
.tabulator{
    font-size:10px;
    color: #F01;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a specific CSS selector for a textbox's placeholder text.

```
.tabulator-header-filter input::placeholder {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this css:
color parameters change text color

```
.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col .tabulator-header-filter input,
.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col .tabulator-header-filter select {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #f2f2f5;
  color: #000;
}
```